# await should wait for complete the task in Dart

Tags: dart, async-await, flutter

I am using **`async await`** in my **Flutter** app to wait for complete execution of first line and then execute the next line, but in my case next line is never called, I tried using debug point too, but never stopped at break point.

I am using [third party library](https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler) for location permission in my Flutter app, check the code snippet below.

```
  void checkPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.location);
    if (permission == PermissionStatus.unknown ||
        permission == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions =
          await PermissionHandler()
              .requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.location]);

      Scaffold.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('${permissions[PermissionGroup.location]}')));
      if (permissions[PermissionGroup.location] == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        platform.invokeMethod('locationPermissionGranted');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: did you add "async" keyword to your method ?

Comment: That just means `checkPermissionStatus(...)` never completes. Breakpoints sometimes don't work. If you want to be sure add a `print('foo');` statement and check the console output.

Comment: Yes I did @diegoveloper

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried print after request permission, but not printing it.

Comment: The for some reason the call never completes.

Comment: What should be the code to complete the call? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: Can you please post whole method definition here?

Comment: Check now @JigneshPatel

Comment: Might be worth splitting the line into two so you can see that the permission handler is created okay.